# How to design an ergonomic software rendering pipeline with painter's algorithm?

Tags: rendering

I wrote my software renderer with C++20 and the DirectX Math library.
The pipeline so far consists of these steps:

1. I use vertex buffers (`std::vector<xgl::Vertex>`) and index buffers (`std::vector<DirectX::UINT3>`).
2. I assemble triangles into a `std::vector<Triangle>` using 144 bytes per triangle multiplied by N. Each vertex takes up 48 bytes.
3. I perform vertex shading/processing using `std::function<Vertex(const Vertex&)>`.
4. I apply culling.
5. I sort the triangles by average depth from farthest to nearest using the painter's algorithm.
6. I perform rasterization or fragment generation`std::vector<Fragment>`. Each fragment occupies 44 bytes. For example, if the resolution is 320x240, the maximum size of fragments would be 3,379,200 bytes.
7. I apply fragment shading using `std::function<DirectX::XMFLOAT4(const Rasterizer::Fragment&)>`.
8. Finally, I output the pixels using `std::function<void(DirectX::XMUINT2, DirectX::XMFLOAT4)>`.

All these steps happen in the `Renderer::DrawTriangles` function:

```cpp
auto SortTriangles(const std::vector<xgl::Triangle>& transformed_triangles)
    -> std::vector<xgl::Triangle>;

class Rasterizer {
 public:
  struct Fragment {
    DirectX::XMUINT2 raster_xy{};
    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 normal{};
    DirectX::XMFLOAT2 texture_uv{};
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4 color{};

    Fragment() = default;

    Fragment(const DirectX::XMUINT2& raster_xy, const DirectX::XMFLOAT3& normal,
             const DirectX::XMFLOAT2& texture_uv,
             const DirectX::XMFLOAT4& color);
  };

  Rasterizer() = default;

  explicit Rasterizer(DirectX::XMUINT2 raster_dimensions)
      : raster_dimensions_{raster_dimensions} {}

  [[nodiscard]] auto RasterizeTriangle(const Triangle& triangle) const
      -> std::vector<Fragment>;

 private:
  DirectX::XMUINT2 raster_dimensions_{};
};

class Renderer {
 public:
  using OnDrawPixelFunction =
      std::function<void(DirectX::XMUINT2, DirectX::XMFLOAT4)>;
  Renderer() = default;
  Renderer(const Renderer&) = default;
  auto operator=(const Renderer&) -> Renderer& = default;
  Renderer(OnDrawPixelFunction&& on_draw_pixel,
           DirectX::XMUINT2 raster_dimensions, bool cull = true);

  auto DrawTriangles(const std::vector<xgl::Vertex>& vertices,
                     const std::vector<DirectX::XMUINT3>& indices,
                     const VertexShader& vertex_shader,
                     const FragmentShader& fragment_shader)
      -> std::pair<size_t, size_t>;

 private:
  OnDrawPixelFunction on_draw_pixel_function_{};
  Rasterizer rasterizer_{};
  bool cull_{};
};
```

This pipeline draws some inspiration from OpenGL, but I have observed the following issues:

- It complicates the implementation of flat shading.
- It necessitates sorting all triangles in the scene, requiring me to merge the triangles before issuing a draw call. In contrast, OpenGL utilizes a depth buffer that stores the "last depth," enabling subsequent draw calls (e.g., DrawTriangles) without concerns about correct ordering.

To make it work, I can append the vertices to another buffer and adjust the indices or add indices, offsetting them by the number of vertices in the first mesh. However, this approach is not user-friendly:

```cpp
auto DrawContent() -> std::pair<size_t, size_t> {
  auto [vertices_1, indices_1] = gCubeData;
  auto [vertices_2, indices_2] = gOctahedronData;

  // Make the second mesh a little distant from the first.
  for (auto vertex : vertices_2) {
    vertex.position.z += 4.0F;
  }

  std::vector<xgl::Vertex> combined_vertices{};
  std::vector<DirectX::XMUINT3> combined_indices{};

  combined_vertices.insert(combined_vertices.end(), vertices_1.begin(),
                           vertices_1.end());
  combined_indices.insert(combined_indices.end(), indices_1.begin(),
                          indices_1.end());

  combined_vertices.insert(combined_vertices.end(), vertices_2.begin(),
                           vertices_2.end());

  // Add indices from second mesh, offset by the number of vertices in the first
  // mesh.
  for (const auto& index : indices_2) {
    const auto size = static_cast<std::uint32_t>(vertices_1.size());
    const auto new_index =
        DirectX::XMUINT3{index.x + size, index.y + size, index.z + size};
    combined_indices.push_back(new_index);
  }

  auto vertex_shader = LoadVertexShader();
  auto fragment_shader = LoadFragmentShader();
  const auto triangle_and_fragment_count = gRenderer.DrawTriangles(
      combined_vertices, combined_indices, vertex_shader, fragment_shader);
  return triangle_and_fragment_count;
}
```

Furthermore, texturing (affine texture mapping) will become cumbersome as well, I need to store the texture ID somewhere, so that each triangle "knows" what texture it "wants".

In summary, the pipeline

1. Index/Vertex Buffer
2. Triangle Assembly
3. Vertex Shading (vertex transforms)
4. Culling (backface removal)
5. Painter's Algorithm (sorting triangles from farthest to nearest by average depth)
6. Fragment Generation (rasterization)
7. Fragment Shading (final color output using the interpolated vertex attributes, e.g., normal, color etc.)
8. Frame Buffer (pixel output or draw pixel function)

Can you suggest me a more ergonomic pipeline or API design?

The blog post by [David Colson](https://www.david-colson.com/2021/11/30/ps1-style-renderer.html) apparently does not implement painter's algorithm.
So, he can issue `BeginObject` and `EndObject` (the draw call) without worrying about ordering issues, since he uses a depth buffer through OpenGL.

In my opinion, if he were to implement a depth sorting method, then he would actually redesign the API, to first "collect" the triangles, then draw them.

So:

```
BeginObject()
...
EndObject() // Collect all triangles from mesh 1 - a "collect call"
BeginObject()
...
EndObject() // Collect all triangles from mesh 2 - a "collect call"

DrawAllTriangles() // The actual draw call
```

Comment: Beware that sorting  the facets by average depth is not always right if they overlap on XY (nor sorting by the closest or farthest vertex). There are even cases that cannot be arbitrated without splitting some facet.